# RecyclerView тормозит/лагает

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Коллеги, новый день и новый вопрос. Тормозит прокрутка списка, так, будто это очень тяжёлая игра, а у меня слабая видеокарта да и оперативки в компьютере совсем нет. Причём, тормозит и при первом прокручивании вниз (при создании вьюХолдеров) и при возврате к уже существующим элементам. Количество элементов в списке ограничено, состоит каждый элемент из 3х ImageView (48х48, 16х16, 48х48) и 3х TextView. Два из трёх изображений векторные. Данные грузит с интернета и кэширует в список (ArrayList), растровое изображение (обложка) грузится через Glide.
Код адаптера:

```
private static ArrayList <Book> books;
static Context context;

final static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView author;
    TextView length;
    ImageView icon;
    ImageView bookType;
    ImageView bookFace;

    ViewHolder (View view) {
        super (view);
        context = view.getContext();
        this.name = view.findViewById (R.id.name);
        this.author = view.findViewById (R.id.author);
        this.length = view.findViewById (R.id.timeOrPages);
        this.icon = view.findViewById (R.id.icon);
        this.bookType = view.findViewById (R.id.bookType);
        this.bookFace = view.findViewById (R.id.bookFace);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ListActivity listActivity = new ListActivity ();
                int position = getLayoutPosition();

                if (MainActivity.onLine) {
                    if (books.get(position) instanceof AudioBook) {
                        BookActivity.bookType = "audio";
                        BookActivity.book = books.get (position);
                        if (books.get (position).getChapters() != null && books.get (position).getChapters().size() == 1) {
                            BookActivity.actualPosition = (int) books.get (position).getChapters().get(0).currentPosition;
                        }
                        BookActivity.actualChapter = getActualChapter (position);
                        BookActivity.dataHttp = books.get (position).getSystemName();
                        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, BookActivity.class));
                        listActivity.books = null;
                    } else {
                        BookActivity.bookType = "text";
                        BookActivity.book = books.get (position);
                        BookActivity.actualChapter = getActualChapter(position);
                        BookActivity.dataHttp = books.get (position).getSystemName();
                        listActivity.books = null;
                        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, BookActivity.class));
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d (LOG_TAG, "chapter 0 = " + books.get (position).getChapters());
                    String [] path = books.get (position).getChapters().get (0).getAddress().split ("/");
                    String [] bookData = path [path.length - 2].split ("_");

                    switch (path [path.length - 3]) {
                        case ("audio"):
                            BookActivity.bookType = "audio";
                            BookActivity.title = bookData [1];
                            BookActivity.author = bookData [2];
                            BookActivity.actualChapter = getActualChapter(position);
                            BookActivity.book = getBook (bookData [1], "audio");
                            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, BookActivity.class));
                            listActivity.books = null;
                            break;
                        case ("text"):
                            BookActivity.bookType = "text";
                            BookActivity.title = bookData [1];
                            BookActivity.author = bookData [2];
                            BookActivity.actualChapter = getActualChapter(position);
                            BookActivity.book = getBook (bookData [1], "text");
                            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, BookActivity.class));
                            listActivity.books = null;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

public SomeAdapter (ArrayList <Book> books) {
    this.books = books;
}

@Override
public final SomeAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Log.d (LOG_TAG, "onCreate viewHolder");
    View v;
    if (MainActivity.night)
        v = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_night, parent, false);
    else
        v = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder (v);
}

@Override
public final void onBindViewHolder(final NewBiblioAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.name.setText (books.get (position).getName());
    holder.author.setText (books.get (position).getAuthor());
    holder.length.setText(books.get(position).getLength());
    if (books.get (position) instanceof AudioBook) {
        holder.icon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.iconaudio);
        holder.bookType.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.iconaudio);
    }
    else {
        holder.icon.setBackgroundResource (R.drawable.icontext);
        holder.bookType.setBackgroundResource (R.drawable.icontext);
    }
        try {
            Glide.with (context)
                 .load (books.get (position).getCoverPreview ())
                 .into (holder.bookFace);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d (LOG_TAG, "thread exception", e);
    }
}
@Override
public final void onAttachedToRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public final int getItemCount() {
    if (books == null)
        return 0;
    else
        return books.size();
}

private static Book getBook (String bookName, String type) {
    for (int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++) {
        if (books.get (i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase (bookName)) {
            return books.get(i);
        }
    }
    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase ("audio"))
        return new AudioBook ();
    else
        return new TextBook ();
}

private static int getActualChapter (int position) {
    if (books.get (position).getChapters() != null && books.get (position).getChapters().size() == 1) {
        return (int) books.get(position).getChapters().get(0).getId();
    }
    else
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Код XML элемента списка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:theme="@style/SomeTheme"
    android:background="@color/colorBack"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bookFace"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="8dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/author"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/name" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/author" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timeOrPages"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/icon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/author" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bookType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="8dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Второй (night) отличается только цветами.
Код вызова RecyclerView:

```
recyclerView = findViewById (R.id.recyclerView);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager (ListActivity.this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager (layoutManager);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize (true);
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled (false);
DividerItemDecoration verticalDividerDecorator = new DividerItemDecoration (ListActivity.this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
Drawable horizontalDivider;
if (MainActivity.night)
   horizontalDivider = ContextCompat.getDrawable (ListActivity.this, R.drawable.divider_night);
else
   horizontalDivider = ContextCompat.getDrawable (ListActivity.this, R.drawable.divider);
try {
   verticalDividerDecorator.setDrawable(horizontalDivider);
   recyclerView.addItemDecoration (verticalDividerDecorator);
} catch (Exception e) {
   Log.d (LOG_TAG, "divider exception", e);
}
adapter = new SomeAdapter((ArrayList<Book>) books);

recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Что самое интересное - тормозит не на всех телефонах и зависит это не от параметров телефона (на моём, послабже, летает, на телефоне коллеги, помощнее, лагает ужасно, аж смотреть противно).

Comment: Кастомные шрифты не используете?

Comment: Нет, не использую.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я нашёл проблему. Возможно, это не 100 процентов решения, однако, большую часть вопроса точно решает. Проблема была в Over Draw (в перерисовке элементов). За моим списком было ещё два элемента во весь экран - основная тема приложения и фон, который я ставил для загрузки и потом не убирал (не посчитал это важным). Для тех, кто уже копал в эту сторону: я тоже просматривал этот вопрос раньше, и просто не подумал, что всего два (хотя я-то думал, что вообще один, тут мой косяк) дополнительных слоя могут поднять фпс в 4-5 (!) раз. Оказалось, что в вопросе списка это очень важно.
Что я смотрел, чтоб дойти до решения - мониторил фпс. Встроенными средствами Андроид (Режим разработчика - Профиль обработки GPU - на экране в виде полос). Ссылка на видео со специалистом от гугла https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VzYkVL1n4M8&index=24&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE 
И, конечно же, сам Over Draw, то есть наложение слоёв, тот же Режим разработчика - Отладка превышения GPU - Показывать области наложения.
ФПС для хорошей работы - меньше 16. Мой результат 5-10 при листании списка.
Всем благодарен за уделённое время и внимание.

Answer (score 0):

Загрузка в onBindViewHolder(). В этом методе не должно происходить тяжёлых загрузок, возможно в этом причина.

```
try {
    Glide.with (context)
        .load (books.get (position).getCoverPreview ())
        .into (holder.bookFace);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d (LOG_TAG, "thread exception", e);
```

Сделайте проверку на нахождение нужных в данных в кеше, если они есть то загрузите их из кеша в этом методе, если нету, вынесите загрузку из Glide этих данных в отдельный поток.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Однако, даже если совсем убрать подгрузку картинок в адаптер (и вообще в RecyclerView) - ничего не меняется...

Comment: Скорее всего у вас проблема в onBindViewHolder(), попробуйте закомментировать содержимое этого метода и посмотреть пропадут ли лаги. Если не пропадут, то значит у вас проблема в конструкторе ViewHolder.